# Hibernate detachedcriteria for 2 joined-subclasses with the same property

Tags: hibernate, subclass, hibernate-criteria

I have the following mapping:

```
<class name="Animal" table="Animal" abstract="true">

    <id name="Id" column="Id" type="Guid">
       <generator class="guid.comb"/>
    </id>

    <joined-subclass name="Dog" table="Dog" lazy="false">
       <property name="Name" column="Name" type="String" length="100" not-null="true"/>
    </joined-subclass>

    <joined-subclass name="Cat" table="Cat" lazy="false">
       <property name="Name" column="Name" type="String" length="100" not-null="true"/>
    </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

Here is my search criteria:

```
Sessoion.CreateCriteria("Animal")
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Name", "Pluto"))
    .List<Animal>();
```

The query that is generated by the search criteria only queries Dog table for Name = "Pluto." It does not query over Cat table.

Does anybody know how to query both tables where Name="Pluto"?

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using? I'm facing the same problem with Hiberante 3.3 and I'm afraid I'll have to find a workaround, because this is a known bug:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4829